# Salesforce Trustpilot Integration

Tags: integration

I have a requirement to send a service review request once a survey with score above 7 is received in Salesforce. Is this something I can accomplish with a trigger and apex code? What would the Apex code look like. This is my first SF integration and I'm a little confused on the best way to get this done. Do I need to use an external app?

```
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://invitations-api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/business-units/{businessUnitId}/email-invitations');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    //Set the body as a JSON object
    request.setBody('{
       "consumerEmail":"myemail@gmail.com",
       "referenceNumber":"Test1234",
       "consumerName":"Test Tester",
       "locale":"en-US",
       "serviceReviewInvitation":{
          "tags":[
             "tag1",
             "tag2"
          ]
       },
       "senderName":"Testing Review Form"
    }');
    HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

Comment: Take a look at this Trailhead module (https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services) below. Note that this question will be closed as it does not show what have you tried. On this site, we expect an MRC (Minimum Reproducible Code)

Comment: I have seen this trailhead and tried it but this doesn't show how to pass an api key and secret.

Comment: Can you add what you tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: I updated my question to include the code I have. I'm just stuck on authentication. I have a trustpilot api key and secret. I just need to know how I can pass these. I'm also not sure if I can just call this apex code from a trigger or if I need anything else.

Comment: Reading from docs you can use setHeader to set the api keys! You can use the trigger to invoke a queueable apex call!